# Generate HTML Web Page using ASP.NET MVC controller and view, without project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, roslyn

Let's say I have two files:

1. HomeController.cs (controller with Index method)
2. Index.cshtml (Razor view that takes IndexViewModel from HomeController.Index method)

How can I compile and run them to generate html for a web page?
Best would be to do it in memory without generating anything on disk.

Comment: Can you explain the motive or this, it's hard to make sense of.

Comment: I am writing a sandbox tool, so a person can enter Controller code and View code and I can generate HTML page for them to see how it will look.

Comment: Razor is deeply tied into the Asp.Net framework libraries, and doesn't compile as just a single file.  What you are attempting to do is not trivial, and would involve re-engineering the existing Razor implementation.  The Razor syntax is essentially C# code, every Razor command is eventually interpreted as a .Net Function which returns strings of HTML content.